# How do I prioritize a job created with the delayed_jobs gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem like this:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue Note.new(parameter_hash)
```

The jobs are processed by Heroku workers. I need to prioritize some jobs. I know there is a priority setting for delayed_job, but I'm not sure how to use it with the above job creation line.

How do I make a job higher priority?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the docs, by default jobs are scheduled with a priority of 0--which is the highest priority.  In this case, lower numbers have higher priorities.

To schedule some jobs at different priorities, use:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue Note.new(parameter_hash), :priority => 10
```

Again, though, lower number = higher priority.  A job with a priority of 0 is higher priority than one with 10.